# how to get only numeric values avoiding qoutes numeric values?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have code that below:

```
if ((!isNaN(abc[i][j])) == [0-9]) {                         
    count[i][j] = abc[i][j];            
} else {
    count[i][j] = "";   
}
```

Here abc is an array. 
link: http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html. I tried to add the regex code as in if condition like below show:
    [0-9] and entered 100 gives 100. Okay, now if I try to put "100" still gives me 100 output. I wanted only numeric values without any qoutes numberic values to accept. How to get it? Referred to W3schools, couldn't get idea how to avoid it.

Comment: I feel like checking isNaN is overkill if you're going to regex it.

Comment: use the anchors like `^[0-9]+$`

Comment: also id like to comment that w3schools is the worst place to learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex

```
(/^\d+$/).test(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this. You can just `typeof` it.

```
if (typeof abc[i][j] === "number") {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(abc[i][j].search(/\D/) > -1) {  /*there is some non numeric characters*/ }
```

`isNaN("100")` will returns false. if you need to treat "100" as NaN then use the above regex
if you need "100" to be concerned as a number then use

```
parseFloat(abc[i][j])
parseFloat("100") will be 100
parseFloat("100as") will be 100
parseFloat("10a0as") will be 10
```